# Entity Framework queries speed

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Recently I started to learning Entity Framework.

First question made in my mind is:

When we want to use LINQ to fetching data in EF, every query like this:

```
var a = from p in contacts select p.name ;
```

will be converts to SQL commands like this :

```
select name from contacts
```

1. does this converting repeat every time that we are querying?
2. I heard that stored procedures are cached in database, does this event happens in LINQ queries in Entity Framework ?

And at last is my question clear?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/performance_comparisons.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQquery.aspx http://dotnetkicks.com/architecture/Performance_comparison_between_Linq_NHibernate_and_Stored_Procs http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/03/17/linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-entity-framework-performance.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are all sorts of optimizations being made, both in the linq expression caching and what SQL server chooses to cache, the only way is to measure your performance speed and memory consumption

To see what SQL is created you can use http://efprof.com/ which I've found quite good. You can get *some* of this info through SQL profiler, it's just a lot more work.

Answer (score 7):

I think linq query is converted each time you want to execute it. To improve performance you can use [compiled queries](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/compiled-queries-in-entity-framework/).

Comment: Yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.compiledquery.aspx